# Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction : The pipeline has been stopped

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

Occasionally when executing *Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction* poweshell command I get the following exception.

> Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction : The pipeline has been stopped.
>   Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -R ...
>   + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction], PipelineStoppedException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.InvokAzureResourceAction 
>   Cmdlet

How should I treat this error? Do should I catch it and retry? It normally works to just rerun the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ForEach-Object commandlet, try to replace it with foreach statement.

```
# your code like this
Get-Something | ForeachObject {Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction $_} 
# replace with this
foreach ($Obj in Get-Something) {
  Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction $Obj
}
```